# getting certain keys from python dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter, key

I have a python dict and following is an output of the keys of the dict:

```
type(es_dict)
<class 'dict'>
type(es_dict.keys())
<class 'dict_keys'>

es_dict.keys()
dict_keys(['b_Biomass_Mid', <class 'oemof.solph.blocks.Bus'>,
           'b_Coal_Mid', 'b_Gas_Mid', 'b_Lignite_Mid', 'b_Elec_Mid',
           's_Biomass_Mid', <class 'oemof.solph.blocks.Flow'>,
           's_Coal_Mid', 's_Gas_Mid', 's_Lignite_Mid', 'rs_Hydro_Mid',
           <class 'oemof.solph.blocks.InvestmentFlow'>, 'rs_Solar_Mid',
           'rs_Wind_Mid', 'pp_Biomass_Mid', <class 'oemof.solph.blocks.Transformer'>,
           'pp_Coal_Mid', 'pp_Gas_Mid', 'pp_Lignite_Mid', 'Elec_Mid',
           'storage_Elec_Mid', 'b_Biomass_South', 'b_Coal_South',
           'line_Mid_North', 'line_North_South', 'line_Mid_South'])
```

I would like to collect the keys which have `'line'` in them to a python list.

To do so I am using following code-piece:

```
list = []
for key in es_dict.keys():
    if 'line' in key:
        list.append(key)
```

But I am getting following error:

```
    if 'line' in key:
TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable
```

How to fix this?

Comment: some keys of your dict are classes !!! `<class 'oemof.solph.blocks.Bus'>`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes I know? it is probably the reason of the error. But how would I fix it?

Comment: If it's a class you need to specify `"line" in key.name` or whatever your getter method is.

Comment: @oakca Please know having classes as keys is probably very bad, and this issue is just one you would encounter going forward. I suggest you should clean/remodel the dictionary.

Comment: to be honest the dict is created via a python package. So I have no way of changing it. I needed a workaround and @blhsing 's answer works well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the keys of `es_dict` are class objects, which are not iterable. You can add a condition to ensure that the key is a string before using the `in` operator to check if `'line'` is a substring of it:

```
if isinstance(key, str) and 'line' in key:
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue with your code, but with how your `dict` is created. Some of keys in your dict is *types/classes*, not instances. I.e. `<class 'oemof.solph.blocks.Bus'>`

This is a bug, most probably. Take a look into piece of code that's creating this mapping.